# laravel 4 form macro: Method fullName does not exist

Tags: laravel-4

I'm confused by the creation of Laravel 4 Form Macro. To create a custom Form Macro I did three things:
1) app/macros.php

```
<?php
Form::macro('f', function()
{
    return '<p>Full name: <input type="text" name="full_name"></p>';
});
```

2) app/routes.php

```
Route::get('/f', function(){
    return Form::f();
)};
```

3) start/global.php

```
app_path().'/macros.php'
```

But when I go /hostlocal/f, Laravel return "Method f does not exist." Can anyone find the problem??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just missed to add "require" at the end of */app/start/global.php*.

```
require app_path().'/macros.php';
```

After adding that it should work.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried to add require at the end of globel.php and delete the 3rd manipulation and it worked. So the **require** manipulation is all we need?

Comment: There is not a place where you must put your macros, you can put them in global.php directly if you wanted

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't express my idea correctly. I mean I only need to add **require app_path.'/macros.php'** at the end of **global.php** then the custom form macro will work, and I **donot** need to add another time **app_path().'/macros.php'** inside of **ClassLoader::addDirectories(array( app_path ...));**. I did the latter according to some blogs but it didn't work.

Comment: you only need to require once on global. and you cau use your form macro where ever. normaly form macros are used in templates.